# Why is this Maven build failing to compile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have an existing application that I'm trying to break apart to separate some common code that will be used by another new application. All of this code is using Java 11 and also utilizes Spring Boot. Maven is used to manage building the applications.

I created a new Maven project and moved the common code into it. It builds and installs its jar file into my local maven (.m2) repo. I then removed the common code from the existing app and added the common jar as a dependency. For some reason it fails to compile with errors like:

```
[ERROR] /C:/Users/jgagnon/workspace/prometheus-metrics-and-rules/src/main/java/com/beastcode/devops/prometheus/types/ReferenceTreeAggregation.java:[6,45] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ExpressionToken
  location: package com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.types
```

Here is the pom.xml for the common project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.14</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  
  <groupId>com.beast-code.devops</groupId>
  <artifactId>prometheus-common</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    
    <slf4j.version>1.7.36</slf4j.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.19.0</log4j2.version>

    <json-path.version>2.7.0</json-path.version>
    <j2html.version>1.6.0</j2html.version>
  </properties>
  
  ...

  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Set layout to NONE, as there is no main class. -->
          <layout>NONE</layout>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Here is the pom.xml for the existing project that has a dependency on the common project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.14</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  
  <groupId>com.beast-code.devops</groupId>
  <artifactId>prometheus-metrics-ref</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.5</version>
  
  <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    
    <slf4j.version>1.7.36</slf4j.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.19.0</log4j2.version>
    
    <prometheus-common.version>1.0.0</prometheus-common.version>
  </properties>
  
  ...
  
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.beast-code.devops</groupId>
        <artifactId>prometheus-common</artifactId>
        <version>${prometheus-common.version}</version>
      </dependency>

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  
  <dependencies>
    
    ...
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.beast-code.devops</groupId>
      <artifactId>prometheus-common</artifactId>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
</project>
```

I've run the `mvn clean compile` command with the `-X` flag to show debug output. It looks to me that it's recognizing the dependency on the common jar file, but during compilation cannot find what it needs.

One thing to note is that there is common Java package naming between the new common project and the existing project that is trying to use the new project. For example, the existing app has a `com.beastcode.devops.prometheus.types` package that contains classes used by the app. The common project has the same path, containing the common classes that the existing app and a future app will both use. There is no overlap as far as the classes themselves, just the same package "path". Could this be responsible for the build failure?

I don't think so, as I tried an experiment where I changed the package name in the common project. When I ran  the build, it still couldn't find the classes.

Comment: Remove the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` from the common project, that is just a regular project and shouldn't be build with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Even though I'm using the Spring Boot starter as a parent? What should I be using in its place in the `<build>` block? I removed the spring-boot-maven-plugin as suggested, but now it fails to install. `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) on project prometheus-common: Failed to install artifact com.beast-code.devops:prometheus-common:jar:1.0.0: ...`

Comment: Please don't add information in comments that is totally unreadable. You shouldn't need to add anything as it it should just build a jar. The fact that you use Spring Boot Starter as a parent doesn't mean you must use the plugin, you should only use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` if you want to have an executable fatjar or war, if not don't use it. Running `mvn install` or `./mvnw install` should build the jar and put in in your `.m2` directory. If you get an error please add the full exception to your question.

Comment: ??? What was unreadable? Looks good to me.
In any case, it fails to compile. What should I used to replace the spring boot maven plugin?

Comment: The error message as there is more hence it is cut off and unreadable. As stated you don't need to replace it with anything, the regular jar plugin will kick in to make the jar.